# How to resolve merge conflict in a submodule when merging the feature root module to master branch root module?

Tags: git, github, merge, git-submodules, conflict

I am having issues when merging from a feature root module branch say "feature-A" having 5 submodules to master branch having same number of submodules, since its the same repository.

It's showing conflict on one of the submodules as github shows. However, the submodules itself have merged to their respective masters and I pushed the submodules to the the feature root module branch and then trying to merge it root module master.

Visualization ---

```
      |        Root Module                           |
      |    Feature A |       master                  |
      |: -----------:|: --------------------------- :|
      |     Sub1 ->  | <tree commit of prev master>  |
      |     Sub2 ->  | <tree commit of prev master>  |
      |     Sub3 ->  | <tree commit of prev master>  |
      |     Sub4 ->  | <tree commit of prev master>  | ---Conflict
      |     Sub5 ->  | <tree commit of prev master>  |
```

The submodules in feature A have all merged to their masters and the master root module have tree commits of previous masters.

Github asks me to do the following in this case:

1. Git checkout origin/feature-A
2. Git merge master

Then, Merge the changes and push to github

1. git checkout master
2. git merge --no-ff feature-A
3. git push origin master

The above approach works well for a branch without submodules, how will it work for one with submodules? Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Before merging to the `master` or some other branch you need to be sure you commited everything in master `branch`. `git status` must be clean before `git merge`

Comment: This shows up on GitHub not on my local. So, there is a difference. On local can I still check the files which are not committed. But, on GitHub everything is done by tool. So, it's showing merge conflict on the root module merge from the feature root module. And the conflict is on the submodule package.